# Why is the program setting it to "else" when it should be on "if" here?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, random, picturebox

I am developing a game.

There is a picturebox on the scene and the image for the picturebox is set in an array that changes randomly after the user answers the correct name of the image in a textbox.

I have now set it up that a Int variable increase on correct and decrease by wrong.

It will play a specific sound for correct and a specific sound for wrong.

Why I debug, 
it works as it should a few times and then,
by button 1 click, 
it goes to else instead of if.

So I do not increase the Int and plays the wrong audio, even though the right input is set in the textbox. Here is the code :

```
namespace AngelinaSkriver2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Bitmap[] bildeListe = new Bitmap[4];

    int poengInt;

    Random r = new Random();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bildeListe[0] = Properties.Resources.ål;
        bildeListe[1] = Properties.Resources.ant;
        bildeListe[2] = Properties.Resources.apple;
        bildeListe[3] = Properties.Resources.arm;

        pictureBox1.Image = bildeListe[r.Next(0, 3)];

    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int tilfeldigBildet = r.Next(0, 3);
        SoundPlayer riktigLyd = new SoundPlayer("lyd/applause.wav");
        SoundPlayer feilLyd = new SoundPlayer("lyd/feil.wav");

        if (pictureBox1.Image == bildeListe[0])
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower() == "ål")
            {

                riktigLyd.Play();

                poengInt += 1;

                textBox1.Text = "";

                pictureBox1.Image = bildeListe[tilfeldigBildet];

            }
            else
            {

                feilLyd.Play();

                poengInt -= 1;

                textBox1.Text = "";
            }

            String poengString = poengInt.ToString();
            label1.Text = poengString;

        }


        if (pictureBox1.Image == bildeListe[1])
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower() == "maur")
            {

                riktigLyd.Play();

                poengInt += 1;

                textBox1.Text = "";

                pictureBox1.Image = bildeListe[tilfeldigBildet];

            }
            else {

                feilLyd.Play();

                poengInt -= 1;

                textBox1.Text = "";
            }

            String poengString = poengInt.ToString();
            label1.Text = poengString;

        }

        if (pictureBox1.Image == bildeListe[2])
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower() == "eple")
            {

                riktigLyd.Play();

                poengInt += 1;

                textBox1.Text = "";

                pictureBox1.Image = bildeListe[tilfeldigBildet];
            }
            else
            {

                feilLyd.Play();

                poengInt -= 1;

                textBox1.Text = "";
            }

            String poengString = poengInt.ToString();
            label1.Text = poengString;

        }

        if (pictureBox1.Image == bildeListe[3])
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower() == "arm")
            {

                riktigLyd.Play();

                poengInt += 1;

                textBox1.Text = "";

                pictureBox1.Image = bildeListe[tilfeldigBildet];
            }
            else
            {

                feilLyd.Play();

                poengInt -= 1;

                textBox1.Text = "";
            }

            String poengString = poengInt.ToString();
            label1.Text = poengString;

        }

    }
```

I can´t seem to find anything that should make it not work, am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1):

Can't say why from this code. You have made sure the texts are exactly as they should in the text box in debug?

But some general suggestions: do use textBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower() and compare that. Then you don't have to check for that many different versions.

Why aren't the words in an array too if the images are? Then you'd only need one comparison. Just store the index of the image/word and that's that. Comparing image objects is not the best way even though it works.

And not poengInt += -1; but rather poengInt -= 1; is better and easier to understand.

Why do you create instances of SoundPlayer in the start for correct and false, then create them again in when actually playing the sound?

Also do use explanatory variable names from the start, not textBox1, Form1 etc. It makes it so much easier in the long run.

Comment: or even poengint-- and a function to test texts?

Comment: Yes, the text is correct. :) I will apply some of the changes you suggest also.

Comment: If the question shows an apple, I will enter "Apple". I will show correct. Apple shows again, and once again I will enter "Apple" but now it don´t work. It plays the error sound.